# Can I edit an incremental resistance of zener diode in PSPICE?

Tags: diodes, zener, pspice

[image]It seems like breakdown voltage and current of zener diode model in PSPICE can be edited like the screenshot I've uploaded(BV, IBV).
But I want to change the incremental resistance of diode(Rz). 
Is that possible on the PSPICE?

Comment: I don't know how it's done in PSpice, but in LTspice you can set `Rs={x}` and then either define the `x` parameter separately, `.param x=...`, or directly `.step` it. I'm sure PSpice must allow something similar.

Comment: REDOC, by "incremental resistance" do you mean the instantaneous differential slope of the diode curve at some operating point?

Answer (score 1):

[image: PSPICE diode parameter]

There is the table for editing diode in PSPICE. If anyone who has problem like mine, you should add the value RS in the last line.

http://wictronic.ch/Downloads/PSpice/Version_10_5/manuals/PSpice_AD_Language_Reference_10_5.pdf